# Ищу js библиотеку, которая заменяет Е на Ё в словах

Tags: javascript, словари, библиотека

Друзья, нужна ваша помощь! Ищу библиотеку, которая содержит словарь для автозамены букв Е на Ё в словах. Есть ли такие?

Comment: @MoloF ну так товарищ хочет чтобы в слово `еж` стало `ёж`, а например слово `лес` осталось лесом, это именно словарь

Comment: [**eyo**](https://github.com/e2yo/eyo-kernel), [**CLI-версия**](https://github.com/e2yo/eyo). Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных дайте ответ.

Comment: @doox911, я мог бы дать подробный ответ по eyo, поскольку [**давно**](https://github.com/e2yo/eyo/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aclosed) ей [**пользуюсь**](https://github.com/e2yo/eyo-kernel/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aclosed), но вопросы по поиску библиотек тут обычно [**закрывают**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), хоть [**более популярно другое мнение**](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2619/199934) на этот счёт. Переформатирование в «Как сделать X?» вместо «Ищу библиотеку, которая делает X» тоже не всегда помогает. Спасибо.